# Shiny markdown application - Google Analytics integration

Tags: r, google-analytics, markdown, shiny

I'm looking into publishing an R markdown document directly to shinyapps.com (as described in the [official shiny documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/rmd-integration.html)).

I would like to know how many people visit the application/page. In order to get this information I would like to integrate Google Analytics tracking. The official shiny [documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html) describes a method to track a shiny app, but not a markdown document.

This setup only explains how this can be done for a shiny app by integrating it in the ui.R file. Could somebody explain how this can be done in a simple R markdown file (hosted on shinyapps.io)?

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: Shinyapps.io comes with basic analytics, available at https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/application/YOURNUMBER/metrics . You can use this rather than google analytics as a easy first step.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Makes more sense indeed!